# Embedded except block not functioning as intended

Tags: python

i am having unexpected results for the function that retrives passwords (under password generator comment), when the length of the input (website) is equal to zero the code raises a KeyError but instead of entering exception block for the KeyError and tell the user to enter the name of the website. it exits the except error for KeyError and the try block it is embedded into and then it raises the exception for the FileNotFound Error and evaluates the code in it which is not what it is supposed to be doing.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import json

# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #


def retrieve_password():

    try:
        with open("data.json", mode="r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)

            website = website_input.get().lower()

            try:
                email = data[website]["Email or Username"]
                password = data[website]["Password"]
                messagebox.showinfo(title="Email and Password Retrieval", message=f"Email: {email}\nPassword: {password}")
                window.clipboard_append(password)
                window.clipboard_append(email)
                website_input.delete(0, END)

            except KeyError:

                if len(website) == 0:
                    messagebox.showinfo(title="Website name not entered",
                                        message="Please enter the name of the website!")

                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo(title="Log in details do not exist",
                                        message=f"Log in details for {website} do not exist in the database!")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Log in details do not exist",
                            message=f"Log in details for {website_input.get().lower()} do not exist in the database!")


def password_generator():

    characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890~`!@#$%^&*()_+{[}]:;,<.>/?|"
    length = random.randint(14, 18)
    password_list = [random.choice(characters) for character in range(length)]
    password = "".join(password_list)
    return password


def output_password():

    password = password_generator()
    password_output.delete(0, END)
    password_output.insert(END, password)
    window.clipboard_append(password)

# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #


def save_passwords():

    if len(website_input.get()) > 0 and len(email_or_username_input.get()) > 0 and len(password_output.get()) >= 14:

        website = website_input.get().lower()
        email = email_or_username_input.get()
        password = password_output.get()

        new_data = {

            website: {
                "Email or Username": email,
                "Password": password
            }
        }

        try:
            with open("data.json", mode="r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                data.update(new_data)

            with open("data.json", mode="w") as file:
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

                password_output.delete(0, END)
                email_or_username_input.delete(0, END)
                website_input.delete(0, END)

        except FileNotFoundError:

            with open("data.json", "w") as file:
                json.dump({}, file)

            with open("data.json", mode="r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)
                data.update(new_data)

            with open("data.json", mode="w") as file:
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

                password_output.delete(0, END)
                email_or_username_input.delete(0, END)
                website_input.delete(0, END)

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Field(s) not filled", message="Please fill all the fields and make sure the password"
                                                                 " has 14 characters or more!")


# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=189)
image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 94.5, image=image)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=(0, 100))

website_label = Label(text="Website :")
website_label.grid(column=0, row=3, pady=5, padx=10)

website_input = Entry(width=25)
website_input.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=5, padx=20, sticky=W)
website_input.focus()

search_password_button = Button(text="Search", command=retrieve_password, width=15, height=1)
search_password_button.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E, pady=5, padx=20)

email_or_username_label = Label(text="Email/Username :")
email_or_username_label.grid(column=0, row=4, pady=5, padx=10)

email_or_username_input = Entry(width=50)
email_or_username_input.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=5, padx=20)

password_label = Label(text="Password :")
password_label.grid(column=0, row=5, pady=5, padx=10)

password_output = Entry(width=25)
password_output.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=W, pady=5, padx=20, )

generate_password_button = Button(text="Generate Password", command=output_password, width=15, height=1)
generate_password_button.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky=E, pady=5, padx=20)

save_password = Button(text="Add", command=save_passwords, width=42)
save_password.grid(column=1, row=6, pady=10)


window.mainloop()
```

[![logo image used for the password generator][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz7jB.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to fix the problem hours after just staring at the code and minutes after posting here asking for help.

i took out the KeyError for the input being empty and evaluted it first using if and else statements.

```
def retrieve_password():
    website = website_input.get().lower()

    if len(website) > 0:
        
        try:
            with open("data.json", mode="r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)

        except FileNotFoundError:
            messagebox.showinfo(title="Log in details do not exist",
                                message=f"Log in details for {website_input.get()} do not exist in the database!")

        else:

            try:
                email = data[website]["Email or Username"]
                password = data[website]["Password"]
                messagebox.showinfo(title="Email and Password Retrieval", message=f"Email: {email}\nPassword: {password}")
                window.clipboard_append(password)
                window.clipboard_append(email)
                website_input.delete(0, END)

            except KeyError:
                messagebox.showinfo(title="Log in details do not exist",
                                    message=f"Log in details for {website} do not exist in the database!")

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Website name not entered",
                            message="Please enter the name of the website!")
```